# Code coverage issues

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

I am new to salesforce, and hence did not know how to write a test class.
I am unable to cover this class.
Please can somebody help me to write a test class for given below.

```
public with sharing class ExternalPaymentController {
    public string mytrans{get;set;}
    public Payment__c pay{get;set;}

    public ExternalPaymentController(){
        Id paymentID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        pay = [select ID, name,PayerFirstName__c,PayerLastName__c,Payment_Method__c,Credit_Card_Type__c,Credit_Card_Number__c,CreditCardExpirationDate__c,Debit_Card_Type__c,Debit_Card_Number__c,CVV__c,DebitCardExpirationDate__c from payment__c where Id=: paymentID];
    }

    public PageReference saveDetails() {
        try{
             pay.Status__c = 'Verified';
             update pay;

        }
        Catch(System.DMLException e){
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: There are resources out there that helps you write a basic test class.  You should start there and when you get stuck at a specific point in writing the test then come back with a question. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help get you started, commented to help you understand.

```
// Create a dummy record for use in this test class
payment__c pay = new payment__c();
insert pay;

// Set the current page to your Visualforce Page and insert the Id we just generated into the URL
PageReference pg = Page.YourVisualforcePageNameGoesHere;
Test.setCurrentPage(pg);

pg.getParameters().put('id', pay.Id);

// Instantiate the controller and call the saveDetails() method
ExternalPaymentController controller = new ExternalPaymentController();

controller.saveDetails();

// Check that Status__c has actually been updated
query = [SELECT Id. Status__c FROM payment__c WHERE Id = :pay.Id];

System.assertEquals(query.Status__c, 'Verified');

// Check saveDetails() returns null
PageReference pageRef = controller.saveDetails();

System.assertEquals(pageRef, null)
```

This might not necessarily cover everything (the catch block, for example), there might be some compile problems you'll want to debug, but this will, at least, point you in the right direction.

**Edit:**
I suppose I should clarify, the point of test classes is to almost programatically run the application you've made, call certain functions and based on whatever, see what you expect. A super simple example might be that you have a function that does some simple addition.

```
public Integer add(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}
```

To test this, you'd want to provide 2 parameters and assert that you get back what you expect. For example,

```
MyController c = new MyController;

Integer result = c.add(2, 2);
System.assert(result == 4);
```

In other words, you know 2 + 2 is 4 and you know that this particular function should return 4 when something is passed in there. We're just assigning the variable result to the value returned by this function and asserting that the variable result should equal 4, if it doesn't we've got a problem, if it does, great! It works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work for you. Try to learn from the inline comments.

```
@isTest
public class myTestClass {

    static testMethod void myTest() {

       //Create new Payment object record 
       Payment__c payment = new payment__c;
       //write other fields
       insert payment;
       System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('id', payment.id)
       ExternalPaymentController objExternal = new ExternalPaymentController();
       //call save details method.
       PageReference pageRef = objExternal.savedetails();
       //assert value
       system.assertequals(null,pageRef);
     }
}
```